# Возможно ли сказать "осушаться от"

Tags: словосочетания

Возможно ли сказать:
"Северная земля продолжала осушаться от индейского духа" (смысл предложения: индейцы Северной Америки продолжали вымирать).
Вопрос: использование слова "осушаться" с предлогом "от".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Само выражение ''осушаться от индейского духа"  уже некорректно, даже в переносном смысле.

Глагол ''осушить'' имеет следующие значения: ***Сделать сухим, отведя воду, удалив влагу.*** О. болото. Глаз не осушил кто-л. (постоянно, много, часто плакал).
***Выпить содержимое какого-л. сосуда (обычно о спиртном).*** О. бокал вина. О. залпом что-л. О. все 
бутылки.***(Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов).***

Из вашего примера выходит, что индийский дух представлен в виде влаги или воды, что является абсурдным.  Если, предположим, употребить кавычки для обозначения условности этого глагола, тогда исказится смысл, будет восприниматься с иронией.

Answer (score 3):

Дух - субстанция не жидкая, а условно газообразная. Он способен напр. "выветриваться", "улетучиваться", "рассеиваться" и т.п.

**P.S.** По поводу вымирания коренного населения о "земле" можно сказать, что она продолжала "утрачивать" некогда свойственный ей индейский дух.

Comment: Спасибо! Думаю, что "утрачивать" лучше всего подойдёт на замену.

Answer (score 2):

Лучше сказать "Северная земля продолжала терять своих коренных жителей". "Индейский дух", по-моему, вообще здесь некорректен, звучит иронически, будто подчёркивается запах. Дух и душа - всё разные вещи.

Если хочется  сказать о потере душ, возможно так: "Души  продолжали покидать бренные тела индейцев и сиротить древнюю Северную землю".

Comment: Кто-то из классиков говорил о духе и как о "запахе" одного из этносов :)

Там Чингачгука племя чахнет, 
Дух могикан - им уж не пахнет...